# Create Cookie Using Zuul But Not save in Browser (Cross Domain)

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, netflix-zuul, setcookie, zuul-testing

Hi I am using Netflix Zuul for create cookie. I get the cookie in response header but it not show under cookies in browser[image: Cookie Creation of inside Zuul Proxy]

[image: When the response come Cookie is there with Set-Cookie in Response header]

But Cookie not show under Browser -> Application -> Storage -> Cookies
[image]

What Will be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue using adding below configuration.

Client side request should be **withCredential:true** property.
Servicer side (Zuul) need to response with **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true**

Note : this is Cross-site request so response origin must response origin

[image: Use bellow configuration for save and access cookie.]

[image: Zuul CROSS configuration]